# How can i dynamically initialise search module in jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, search

i am dynamically extending a form input field with button click.
what i am appending to the table body is

```
<tr class=rows> <td></td><td> <div  class="ui fluid search id_receipt">
    <div class="ui icon fluid  input">
        <input  class="prompt bordertheme particular" type="text" placeholder="Particulars" >
    </div>
    <div class="results" style="width:100%!important"></div>
</div></td><td><div class="ui small fluid input">
<input type="text" id="id_amount" class="bordertheme fluid centeralign forceamountonly" placeholder="" name="" value="">
```

and the jquery i use to implement the search module is

```
$('.id_receipt').search({
            maxResults: 10,
            selectFirstResult: true,
            source: trans_ledgers,
            onSelect(result, response) {
                receipt = result.id;
               
            }
        });
```

but since the search module is dynamically created the search module is not working anymore.is there any way i can initialise the search function at the time of appending the input fields to the table?

Comment: run the jquery where you are dynamically creating the input?  if you can't do that then use a [mutation observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) to look for changes in the table and then run the jquery when the input is added

Comment: thankyou.i declared a function and then called it everytime the loop is run